# Run two Jenkins alongside agents

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, continuous-integration, selenium-grid

we have a multibranch pipeline that triggers sup-build
the syntax for this like

```
pipeline {
 stages{
   stage('main') {
     agent { label "k8s" }
     sh 'echo hello.'
    }
  }
}
```

I need to add another alongside agent that runs the selenium grid - this agent needs to be active the whole time that the pipeline is active and needs to be deleted after

```
pipeline {
 stages{
   stage('main') {
     agent { label "k8s" }
     sh 'echo hello.'
    }
  stage('SG') {
     agent { label "k8s" }
     sh 'run selenuim-grid'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
Pipeline {
Agent none

Stages {
stage(‘main’)
{
Agent { labe; “k8s”}
Steps { 
Sh ‘echo hello.’
}
}
Stage (‘SG’)
{
Agent {
Kubernetes
{
Label ‘selenium-grid’
Cloud ‘kubernetes’
containerTemplate {
Name ‘selenium’
Image ‘selenium/standalone-chrome’
ttyEnabled true
Command ‘cat’
}}}
Steps
Sh ‘run selenium-grid’
}}}
```

‘SG’ stage has been added to run selenium grid. Once this stage is completed, the pod and container will be automatically deleted.

Please check Jenkins official [page 1](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/) and [Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) for further reference.